# center arabic words or images with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arabic

I want to center the Arabic content (words and images) in the page with tikz. The content is not placed in the center as expected. Any advice?

```
 % !TEX TS-program=lualatex
    \documentclass[a5paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
    %\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
    \definecolor{gris}{HTML}{D7D7D7}
    \usepackage{gradientframe}
    \usepackage{garamondlibre}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[locale=algeria,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node  (image) at (current page.center) {\gradientframe[linewidth=1px,padding =5 mm ]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth,height=0.7\paperheight]{myimage}}};
    \node[font=\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont,below=2ex of image](word) {القراءة};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you refrain from using the `polyglossia` package, your image will be centred as desired:

```
% !TEX TS-program=lualatex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
\definecolor{gris}{HTML}{D7D7D7}
\usepackage{gradientframe}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node  (image) at (current page.center) {\gradientframe[linewidth=1px,padding =5 mm ]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth,height=0.7\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}};
\node[font=\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont,below=-3ex of image](word) {\foreignlanguage{arabic}{القراءة}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with `LuaLaTeX` using a trick like:

```
\node[
    anchor=center,
    xshift=12.5cm,
    yshift=0mm
    ]
```

---

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
\definecolor{gris}{HTML}{D7D7D7}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=algeria,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{gradientframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[
    anchor=center,
    xshift=12.5cm,
    yshift=0mm
    ]  (image) at (current page.center) {\gradientframe[linewidth=1px,padding =5 mm ]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth,height=0.7\paperheight]{example-image-a}}};
    \node[font=\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont,below=-3ex of image](word) {القراءة};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange. I can not reproduce your results. I get the same results as OP independent of `gradientframe`. I assume `lualatex` as in comment. How do you compile?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Hi  
hpekristiansen I compile with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @hpekristiansen With LuaLaTeX compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

Curious: There seems to be a complex interaction between margins, text directionality, total tikz picture size and overlay (=data in .aux file from previous runs) when calculating 'center'.

Keeping `polyglossia`, and using absolute image positioning, no remembered overlay, `geometry`'s default settings plus smaller margins, and slightly scaled down image and caption and caption position gives:

[image: tikz arabic center]

which seems to be stable.

MWE

```
    \documentclass[a5paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
    \definecolor{gris}{HTML}{D7D7D7}
    \usepackage{gradientframe}
    \usepackage{garamondlibre}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[locale=algeria,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Colour=blue]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\captionfont[Scale=2.5,Script=Arabic,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Colour=red]{Amiri}
%    \usepackage{fontspec}
%    \setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    
    
    \begin{document}
\fcolorbox{black}{green!3}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[remember picture,overlay]
    \node  (image) at (current page.center) {%
    \gradientframe[linewidth=1px,padding =5 mm ]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    }%
    };
    \node[below=0.5ex of image](word) {{\captionfont القراءة}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%\selectlanguage{arabic}
%    
%    القراءة
%    
    \end{document}
```